# academic papers about market making

Tags: market-microstructure, market-making, research

I am looking for academic articles which model the p&L of market makers. I have read the Ho-Stoll (1984) article. Is there any recent article on this subject?

Comment: Look for answers of @lehalle here. There are several studies mentioned.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In fact you have three papers available to go further:

- The [Avellaneda-Stoikov](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/HighFrequencyTrading.pdf) one, with proper model and an approximate solution
- The [Bayraktar-Ludkovski](http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.2516) one, with a solution for the linear utility function
- The [L-Guéant-Fernandez](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3115) one, with a full solution for a generic utility function

I prefer the last one ;{)}

To read them, you need to know Stochastic Differential Equations (with jumps) and Stochastic Control (especially Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman expressions of Stochastic Control with jumps).

Comment: Would it possible for you to enlist the topics in quantitative finance that I need to be familiar with to be able to comprehend these papers ? Just to give you my background, I have a bachelor's in mechanical engineering and masters in data science and statistics. I am somewhat familiar with quantitative finance and algorithmic trading but I am looking to delve deeper into it. Thanks

Comment: done @AdnanTamimi

Comment: The proper name of the author of the second referenced paper is Ludkovski

Comment: @DmitryMottl thank you: corrected (and sorry for Mike if he reads this, a problem of lowercase...)