# Text book or distilled guide to market making?

Tags: market-making

Are there any practical articles, blogs or books that describe common practices in market making and how to calculate and use common measures?

The majority of the information I found are research papers. For example, the links in the following question: [academic papers about market making](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8897/academic-papers-about-market-making)

Are there any articles on how the research papers above are used in practice?

Answer (score 2):

I like the question. If you want a practical guide to market making then try the [ACI Dealing Simulation Course](http://aci-uk.com/aci-uk-dealing-simulation-course/). That will sort you out... As for how research papers are used in practise, I think it's about tweaking the model, when a better solution to a common problem comes along.

For example, there is practical value in the paper [Dealing with the Inventory Risk. A solution to the market making problem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.3115) and see all the linked academic papers.